# Restrict input field to alphanumeric only without HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

To restrict an input field to alphanumeric only, I use the following on my site:

```
  <input 
     type="text" 
     name="url_code" 
     pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{4,10}" 
     class="widefat-main" 
     title="4 to 10 alphanumerical characters only" 
     />
```

However for browsers that don't support HTML5, what is the best way to get the same restrictions?

Comment: Try searching for jQuery plugins: https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+input+mask+alphanumeric

Comment: You can use JavaScript right?

Comment: Just to be clear, you will have to use JavaScript and accept that having it disabled a user will not have this level of early error correction/prevention. This is actually part of why it was added to HTML5: to allow error checking without scripting. You will, naturally, still have to check on the server-side to ensure you have received sane data.

Comment: http://javascriptools.sourceforge.net/samples/sample_mask.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use JavaScript to check the input then.  In your `<form>` tag, the `onsubmit` attribute needs to call a function that will return a `boolean` value.  True means that the form will go through, false, means that it won't.

Use a document selector to get the `input` element and then check its `value` attribute.  Make sure it is the right length.  Then match it against a regular expression.  (Learn about them here: [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions))  If everything thing is fine, return true.  Otherwise return false and either print in the console what was wrong or write it to a `<div>`.  If you want a pop-up like you get with the HTML5 way, you'll have to do some other magic.

**Note the `return validate();`**  If you don't include that in your `onsubmit=` then it won't work, you must have the **return**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Validate</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <style>
         .widefat-main{
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         function validate() {
            var errorDiv = document.getElementById("errorDiv"),
                    regex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/,
                    str = document.getElementById("inputString").value;

            if ((str.length > 4) && (str.length < 10) && regex.test(str)) {
               errorDiv.innerHTML = "Fine string";
               return true;
            }
            else {
               errorDiv.innerHTML = "4 to 10 alphanumerical characters only";
               return false;
            }
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="" onsubmit="return validate();">
         <input 
            id="inputString"
            type="text" 
            name="url_code" 
            class="widefat-main" 
            title="4 to 10 alphanumerical characters only" 
            />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </form>
      <div id="errorDiv"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Huh...somebody -1'd this, but didn't comment to suggest improvement. How rude.

Comment: Wasn't the guy who -1'd it, but they probably thought it is too naive of a solution.  I didn't look up this problem because I don't know how to implement alphanumeric filtering.  I was hoping for an answer that mentions some kind of built-in JS method, similar to the HTML5 attribute the OP mentions in his question